# Can't determine difference using diff

Tags: unix, diff, text-files

I have two files I'm trying to compare which appear to be exactly the same, yet when I run diff on them I get the output below...

After looking over this for the better part of an hour, I cannot determine what the difference is. I've even compared the two files one on top of the other using a transparent window app and can't see anything different. Any ideas? Am I missing something? Thanks

```
8c8
<  3 Molly Poultice                 / Ledasha Winnie                  121.88   42.62
---
>  3 Molly Poultice                 / Ledasha Winnie                  121.88   42.62
10c10
<  5 Charlie Anthony Fink           / Xavier Together                 121.33   42.42
---
>  5 Charlie Anthony Fink           / Xavier Together                 121.33   42.42
12,13c12,13
<                1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13
<                -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -    --    --    --    --
---
>                1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13
>                -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -    --    --    --    --
15,16c15,16
< Board  1     8.5   8.5     0   8.5     2     6  ----    11     4     4   8.5     4     1
<              100   100  -500   100  -140    90  ----   150    50    50   100  PASS  -300
---
> Board  1     8.5   8.5     0   8.5     2     6  ----    11     4     4   8.5     4     1
>              100   100  -500   100  -140    90  ----   150    50    50   100  PASS  -300
18,19c18,19
< Board  2     7.5   9.5     2     2   7.5     5  ----    11     6     2   9.5     2     2
<              110   130  -140  -140   110  -110  ----   140   100  -140   130  -140  -140
---
> Board  2     7.5   9.5     2     2   7.5     5  ----    11     6     2   9.5     2     2
>              110   130  -140  -140   110  -110  ----   140   100  -140   130  -140  -140
21,22c21,22
< Board  3    ----  3.80   7.5    11  2.11   7.5   7.5   7.5   7.5  2.11     0  2.11   7.5
<             ----    80   110   140   -50   110   110   110   110   -50  -150   -50   110
---
> Board  3    ----  3.80   7.5    11  2.11   7.5   7.5   7.5   7.5  2.11     0  2.11   7.5
>             ----    80   110   140   -50   110   110   110   110   -50  -150   -50   110
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the `-b` option to `diff` to ignore changes in whitespace and see if your files now match.

Comment: This worked.. the difference had to do with whitespace. Thanks!

Comment: @Nathan No problem.  If you don't mind, please accept this answer so others with similar problems can see this worked.

Answer (score 2):

Was this text file moved between UNIX-like systems and MacOS or Windows? You may have line ending differences if the file was edited or written on different OSes. I would use `od -x` to do a hex dump of the first bit of each file and look at the diff of that.

For instance, the first different line is number 3 so do

```
head -3 <firstfile |od -x >firstfileshort
head -3 <lastfile |od -x >lastfileshort
diff firstfileshort lastfileshort
```

Answer (score 1):

A likely reason for this is different line endings -- diff will show differences where one file has lines ending with `\r\n` (bytes 0x10 0x13), and another has lines ending with `\n` (just byte 0x13).  One or the other file might also have extra spaces on the end of the lines where the other doesn't.